# Specific CSS for individual ion-modal

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453847/alert-like-modal-in-ionic-2). The problem is like as the comment says "modifying this value will make all the modal in your application to use this configuration". In my case I am using padding to `ion-modal`, not `.modal-wrapper` but is just the same thing at this point.

How can I set this CSS to individual ion-modal? Because i have other modals too that I want them to be full screen without that padding.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if my English isn't perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Give a seperate class to your ion-modal in case of modals you want them to be full screen . 
For example -

```
.noPadding{ padding:0px !important}
```

The !important will override the padding on ion-modal element.
Hope this will help !!

Comment: But how can i set that class to a modal which i don't have access? the modal is performed by ionic from angular's code: `let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(Me); modal.present();` when "Me" is a component that i can use CSS on them, but ion-modal is one of his parent tags.

Comment: You can add the class to parent element of your page or the Me component  and then you can target the modal from there . See the refrence here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792886/ionic-framework-popover-jquery-addclass

Comment: No, the modal **is a parent of the page**, take a look at this: http://i.imgur.com/Xb92bEI.png and that reference is for ionic 1.